# Selenium Web-driver Selecting value by index from drop-down menu

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am creating a test to fill out the front end of a registration form, however, I want to click on the arrow for the drop down select the value and then Check that the selected value is the value expected: I can select the value from the dropdown and enter the value, however, the issue I am having is when coming to check that the value selected is the correct one. Code and error is below:

```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#dijit_form_Select_1 > tbody > tr > td.dijitReset.dijitRight.dijitButtonNode.dijitArrowButton.dijitDownArrowButton.dijitArrowButtonContainer > input")).click();


        WebElement Menuitem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#dijit_MenuItem_6_text"));

        boolean click1 = true; 

                Menuitem.click();

                //Checks if drop down button is selected 
                click1 = Menuitem.isSelected();

                if(click1 == false){
                    System.out.println("DropDown Was Selected");
                }else {
                    System.out.println("DropDown was not clicked");
                }



                Select Menuitem6 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Select_1")));   

                Menuitem6.selectByVisibleText("Mr");

                List<WebElement> list = Menuitem6.getOptions();

                for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                    if(list.get(i).getText().equals(Menuitem6.getFirstSelectedOption().getText())){
                        System.out.println("The index of the selected option is: "+i);
                        break;
                        }
```

Error from console: `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "table"`

So the issue is clearly that it is because the html element is a table and not a select, how do I get around this issue?

HTML Code:

```
<tr aria-selected="false" widgetid="dijit_MenuItem_6" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Mr " id="dijit_MenuItem_6" style="-moz-user-select: none;" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" role="option" tabindex="-1">
    <td class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemIconCell" role="presentation">
        <span role="presentation" class="dijitInline dijitIcon dijitMenuItemIcon dijitNoIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></span>
    </td>
    <td id="dijit_MenuItem_6_text" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemLabel" colspan="2" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,textDirNode" role="presentation">Mr</td>
    <td id="dijit_MenuItem_6_accel" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemAccelKey" style="display: none" data-dojo-attach-point="accelKeyNode"></td>
    <td class="dijitReset dijitMenuArrowCell" role="presentation">
        <span data-dojo-attach-point="arrowWrapper" style="visibility: hidden">
            <span class="dijitInline dijitIcon dijitMenuExpand"></span>
            <span class="dijitMenuExpandA11y">+</span>
        </span>
    </td>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML.

Comment: The values are not in a select that's why it isn't working. They are in a table and the values are held in <td>

Comment: If this is selecting Menuitem6.selectByVisibleText("Mr"); the value you want. Use the absolute Xpath to the element where the values are held and then use GetAttribute() to assess.

Comment: I have already selected Mr from the drop-down menu. The drop down is a table and the values are held in <td> so the exception is the element should have been a select but it was a table. I need to be able to get the value of the dropdown once it has been selected. To confirm that the value selected is the correct one. The select method is not going to work here as its a table element.

Comment: You can't use GetAttribute with select. What I am saying is to findElement with the Xpath of  your table element and then use GetAttribute.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML. Only then we can solve your issue.

Comment: @Aritro Sen HTML code added.

Comment: @AlexCharizamhard Can you give an example code of getAttribute then to display it? I have posted the HTML above.

Comment: Is this the HTML after Mr is selected or before?

Comment: This is the HTML when you select MR from the drop down so when the options are displayed. @AlexCharizamhard

Comment: Its very difficult to understand from this piece of HTML. So if possible can you please post the URL ? I can get a better understanding after looking into it then.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a lot of work for asserting that the value selected is correct.

Instead of iterating through all options why not just refer to the same element as when you selected and use GetAttribute("Selected") == true. Especially, if that select function is working on the element.